# Vbscipt Random Generator

Tags: random, vbscript

So I have the following code,

```
max=2000
min=1
Randomize

cntr = 0

StartTime = Timer
Position = 1
set objFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\...\listfile4.csv",2,true)

do while cntr <> 1
    cntr = 0
    Answer = 1
    Lottery = 2
    do while Answer <> Lottery 
        Answer = (Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min))
        Lottery = (Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min))
        cntr = cntr + 1
    loop
    objFile.WriteLine(cstr(Position & "," & cntr & "," & Answer & "," & Lottery & "," & vbtab))
    Position = Position + 1
loop

msgbox (Timer - StartTime)/60
```

Basically I'm choosing two [pseudo]Random Numbers

```
        Answer = (Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min))
        Lottery = (Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min))
```

And trying to see how often they will match on the first try.

So cntr is the count of how many try's it takes for the two numbers to match.
I loop over that loop until it matches on the first try.

When `max` < 2000 it will eventually match on the first try, causing the program to end.

However when `max` >= 2000 it never seems to end. For 2000 the lowest the `cntr` It will produce is `2`.

Here's the weird part, I initially set `max = 10000`. If there is a sufficiently large set of tests (which can be as little as 1000) the minimum `cntr` is always `51` and the max `cntr` is always `57966`

Why is this pattern present, as in why is 51 the minimum? How can I get the minimum `cntr` to 1 in some instances? I would like the program to do something if they match on the first try. However, if my maximum number is larger then 1999 they never match on the first try. This is a problem.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I have to test it, but it seems a side efect of the rounding process in the `Int` function. Replace them with `CLng` and try.

Comment: I did think to test this. `Clng` just ends up returning a different set of standard Min and Max. It makes me think it has something to do with the command(?) `Randomize`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're not really looking for just 2 random numbers in a row being equal but 2 lots of 2. Your inner loop has to find to hit repeated numbers twice in a row.

VBscript calculates the number using a formula - nothings truly random. That's why you need to use randomize, so that you pick up a new random *sequence* of numbers. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231847 gives you the full details

If the numbers were truly random (like a coin toss, dice roll, card draw - ignoring deliberate human manipulation), you'd expect the odds of 2 numbers being identical to be 2000:1 in your script. Finding a repeated pair would also be just 2000:1 as the numbers generated would be stochastically independent. But with a formula, you are creating a sequence of numbers and the next number you get depends on the previous number. The numbers appear random due to rounding caused by multiplying from a float to a whole number (reducing precision) and randomize creating a different starting point in what is ultimately a very long, but single list of numbers.

If you want to understand further, a couple of tweaks to your script might help:

1. Include a totalcount, so you understand just how many loops it takes until you reach the first repeated pair
2. Store the rnd values in a variable and output them, e.g. `r1=rnd    r2=rnd` then use r1 and r2 in your answer and lottery calculations. Output those numbers and you'll see how rounding effects things
3. Try running the code without Randomize or with Randomize X (some number you pick), but with different max values. You'll start seeing the total number of rnd calls to find the repeated pairs alters up and down based on rounding. However, as you increase the max value the trend will be that the total number increases massively. You will find some exceptions - it is psuedo random after all, but generally you will reduce the probability of a repeating pair as you decrease the rounding influence.
4. With a fixed max number, put Randomize (no number) back in. Look at the results you get, you'll find the same pairs of numbers appear multiple times.
5. Just have a single loop, so that you are counting how long till a single repeated number, not a pair of repeats. You should find this comes *closer* to what you would expect statistically.